# js date returning incorrect date based on timezone and dateformat

Tags: javascript, date

Why does the format of my date I pass in affect how the date gets parsed? :(

```
new Date('2018-03-26')
> Sun Mar 25 2018 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
new Date('03/26/2018')
> Mon Mar 26 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

I expect to get back the same result from each of those, yet when I pass in a date as YYYY-MM-DD format, it returns 3/25 instead of 3/26. I don't care about time or timezone at all. Is there anyway to get the same result, since I don't know how the user will enter it? I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require a library like moment.

Comment: ISO 8601 format dates (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD) are treated as UTC. Parsing of anything other than the [subset of ISO 8601 defined in ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) is implementation dependent. It is generally recommended not to use the built-in parser at all, write your own simple parse function or use a library.

Comment: @RobG I wish when it's marked as duplicate, it would link to the duplicate question so I can see the answers :( thanks for your input but it doesn't help me towards finding a solution

Comment: Nevermind I am blind :)

Comment: No problem. This question is asked A LOT, yet the TC39 has yet to see any reason to add decent parsing and formatting capability to Date. It's not as if there aren't plenty of other languages and libraries with good formatters and parsers to model built-in parsing and formatting on.

Comment: Yea I don't know why I was avoiding moment tbh... probably cuz I have 0 other dependencies.. guess I'll bite the bullet ;p

Comment: You don't have to use moment.js. There are a number of much smaller parsing and formatting libraries that are just as good, e.g. [*fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha) which is barely 2k minified and zipped.